# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in Selenium POP

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm learing Selenium and Python and I don't know what is wrong with my code.

I try to using Page Object Pattern. And in my class about page i have this method:

```
def more_than_100(self):
    locator = Locators(self.driver)
    number_of_items = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, locator.return_product_locator())))
    number_of_items.clear()
    number_of_items.send_keys('101')
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='Okulary']/following::button[1]"))).click()
```

and in Locators file i have 2 methods:

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

def return_product_list_input(self):
    titles = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//h4[text()]"))
    for title in titles:
        products.append(title.text)
    return products

def return_product_locator(self):
    locator_product_list_input = "//h4[text()='" + self.return_product_list_input().products[0] + "']/following::input[1]"
    return locator_product_list_input
```

what i want to do is geting all names of products, putting them to list and then using those name to generate xpath. (in future i want to add there some randomness to pick up random product) 
but right now i have

```
File "...\Locators.py", line 12, in return_product_list_input
    titles = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//h4[text()]"))
    TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What should I do with this error? Probably problem is with xpath for H4 but i don't know how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line.

```
titles = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, "//h4[text()]"))
```

as shown below that will resolve the error. (you missed another paranthesis before By)

```
titles = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()]")))
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but right now i got line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Try increasing the timeout from 5 seconds to 30.